# How to resolve this The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. in firestore functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
> AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. To hide this warning and ensure your app does
> not break, you need to add the following code to your app before
> calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
>
> ```
> const firestore = new Firestore();
> const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: true};
> firestore.settings(settings);
> ```
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read
> back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects.
> So you will also need to update code expecting a Date to instead
> expect a Timestamp. For example:
>
> ```
> // Old:
> const date = snapshot.get('created_at');
> // New:
> const timestamp = snapshot.get('created_at');
> const date = timestamp.toDate();
> ```
>
> Please audit all existing usages of Date when you enable the new
> behavior. In a future release, the behavior will change to the new
> behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

**This is my firestore Functions code**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { firestore } = require('../admin');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");



/**
 * Cloud Function: Handle device state updates
 */
module.exports = functions.pubsub.topic('telemetry-topic').onPublish(async (message) => {
  const deviceId = message.attributes.deviceId;
  // Write the device state into firestore
const deviceRef = firestore.doc(`devices/${deviceId}`);
  const deviceTimeRef = firestore.doc(`time/${deviceId}`);
  const deviceupdateTimeRef = firestore.doc(`updatecurrenttime/${deviceId}`);

  var key = new Date().toLocaleDateString()
  var person = {[key]:message.json};
  var key1 = new Date(admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds*1000).toLocaleDateString()
  var person1 = {[key1]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()}
  
  try {
   
    // Ensure the device is also marked as 'online' when state is updated
   await deviceTimeRef.update(person);
   await deviceupdateTimeRef.update(person1);
    console.log(`State updated for ${deviceId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`${deviceId} not yet registered to a user`, error);
  }
  
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a very old version of the Firebase Admin SDK. Just update it to the latest.

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```

Either that, or simply follow the instructions in the error message.